# WordPress Pagination not working Properly with Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I have a WordPress Project. I have page template where I retrieve post type "company". I also have pagination.

Pagination is set up to work in a following way (url):
https://example.com/companies/?paged=2

but instead, it's redirecting to following url:
https://example.com/companies/page/2/

As a result, I get 404 error on both urls.

Although, when I hover the url, it shows https://example.com/companies/?paged=2

Below is the main parts of the code. What can be causing this issue? I would appreciate your help.

```
<?php // Template name: Page - Companies

get_header();

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;

$search_query = isset($_GET['search']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search']) : '';

$args = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'company',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'meta_key'       => 'display_order',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        's'              => $search_query
    )
);
?>

<?php if ( $args->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="grid gap-[30px] xl:gap-[35px_80px] xl:grid-cols-2">
        <?php while ( $args->have_posts() ) : $args->the_post();
            $logo = get_field('logo');
            $rating = get_field('rating') ?? '0.00';
            $address = get_field('address');
            $found_date = get_field('found_date');
            $working_days = get_field('working_days');

            $reviews = get_field('reviews');
            $reviews_count = 0;
            if ($reviews) $reviews_count = count($reviews);

            $avatar = '';
            $branch_slug = get_field('slug');
            $api_url = BACKEND_URL . '/api/frontend/branches/' . $branch_slug;
            $response = wp_remote_get($api_url);
            $branch_data = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);
            $avatar = $branch_data['data']['avatar'];
        ?>
            <!-- My HTML here... -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="flex items-center justify-center gap-[10px] [&_.page-numbers]:flex [&_.page-numbers]:w-[40px] [&_.page-numbers]:h-[40px] [&_.page-numbers]:items-center [&_.page-numbers]:justify-center [&_.page-numbers]:text-center [&_.page-numbers]:text-[14px] [&_.page-numbers]:rounded-[8px] [&_.page-numbers]:bg-light [&_.page-numbers]:transition-colors [&_a.page-numbers:hover]:bg-secondary [&_a.page-numbers:hover]:text-white [&_.icon]:w-[10px] [&_.page-numbers.current]:bg-primary [&_.page-numbers.current]:text-white [&_.page-numbers.current]:text-white mt-[50px]">
        <?php
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'total'        => $args->max_num_pages,
            'current'      => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all'     => false,
            'end_size'     => 1,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => true,
            'prev_text'    => __('<i class="icon icon-chevron-left"></i>'),
            'next_text'    => __('<i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i>'),
            'type'         => 'plain',
        ));
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="text-[#0c3659] font-medium text-[18px] text-center mt-[50px]">No results were found for your search query. Please try again.</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I can tell you that supporting both query string based pagination and path-based ones on an entire site can be troublesome, and it is usually easier to do either one or the other, but not both. If your site is set to show friendly URLs, then you have also opted in for path-based ones, and this is across the board, for all CPTs, taxonomies, etc. There's a couple of fixes, however. The first is that you can try removing the canonical redirect via `remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');`. The other more common is to just use a non-WordPress query string parameter for the page

Comment: Removing the canonical redirect helped. But I have one question, doesn't it affect any other parts of the project?

Comment: Yes, removing that filter does remove other features. This filter is most notable as the one that also makes sure that URLs always (or sometimes always don't) end in slashes. There's probably a bunch of other nuance ones, too, which is why I don't really recommend it.

Comment: I see. Any other solutions you could provide then?

Comment: As noted in my first comment, just use a different query string variable. You aren't using WordPress automatic pagination layout system since you are manually executing a query, so there's no advantage in using their patterns. I think you'll need to register the variable using the [`query_vars`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/) hook. The core list of vars is [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars), and I'd pick something not on that list.